# Removing duplicates from a list with multiple lists

Tags: python, list, loops, duplicates

I have a list with multiple list. The list looks something like that:

[[ Name , Process], [Name2, Process] , [Name, Process1]]

I'm trying to remove Lists with a duplicate Name (duplicate Processes are allowed) and i don't know how i iterate through the first index of all Lists to remove the duplicates.

Can somebody help?

Thanks alot

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: you can get first index, like this [i[0] for i in list]

Comment: Please show the code you've tried along with sample input and expected output

Comment: Please share an exact input and the corresponding expected output

Comment: Expected output would be [[ Name , Process], [Name2, Process] ]

Comment: @Flo What type of objects are in the lists? If you could show an example that would really help

Comment: have you considered using a dictionary here? The keys would be the name and value would be the process.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Making several assumptions about what the input and output requirements are, I think this may work:

```
list_ = [['Name', 'Process'], ['Name2', 'Process'], ['Name', 'Process1']]

d = {}

for n, p in list_:
    d.setdefault(n, p)

print([[k, v] for k, v in d.items()])
```

**Output:**

```
[['Name', 'Process'], ['Name2', 'Process']]
```